# Timer freezes after some time

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, posix, posix-api

I am running the following program which implements a timer. When a thread awake after receiving a signal on condition variable from the previous running thread, it creates a timer and send a signal to the next thread on timer expiration. I want it to run for some time, but the timer stops ticking after some runs.

```
//Import 
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 10

#define CLOCKID CLOCK_REALTIME
#define SIG SIGUSR1
timer_t timerid;

pthread_cond_t   condA[NUM_THREADS+1]  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t  mutex  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
int state = 0;

static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    if(si->si_value.sival_ptr != &timerid){
        printf("Stray signal\n");
    } else {
        //printf("Caught signal %d from timer\n", sig);
    }

        pthread_cond_signal(&condA[state]);
}

void *threadA(void *data_)
{
    int i = 0, s;
    long int loopNum, j;

    int turn = (intptr_t)data_;

    struct timeval tval_result;

    // Timer's part starts

    struct sigevent sev;
    struct itimerspec its;
    long long freq_nanosecs;
    sigset_t mask;
    struct sigaction sa;
    // TImer'spart ends

    while(1)
    {

        /* Wait for state A */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        for (;state != turn;)
        {
            s = pthread_cond_wait(&condA[turn], &mutex);
            if (s != 0)
                perror("pthread_cond_wait");
           // printf("main(): state = %d\n", state);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        //do stuff
        for(j=0;j<10000;j++)
            {//some dummy time consuming works}

        sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
        sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
        sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
        sigaction(SIG, &sa, NULL);

        sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
        sev.sigev_signo = SIG;
        sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
        timer_create(CLOCKID, &sev, &timerid);
        /* Start the timer */

        its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        its.it_value.tv_nsec = 2000;
        its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

        timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        state = (state +1)%NUM_THREADS;
        //pthread_cond_signal(&condA[state]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        // Timer's code ends
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int data = 0;
    int err;

    while(data < NUM_THREADS)
    {
        //create our threads
        err = pthread_create(&tid[data], NULL, threadA, (void *)(intptr_t)data);
        if(err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        else
           // printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");

        data++;
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Although no printf statements are executing, why is it freezing after some time?
If no. of timers are limited, what other strategy should I use to redress this issue?

Comment: These timer instances, where is 'timer_delete' called for them?

Comment: Haven't used, not sure where to call it? I tried calling timer_delete() in the beginning of threadA() function with timerid of the last timer used, but I was getting segfault. It'll be nice of you if you'd suggest me the right place.

Comment: Can you not just re-use one timer?  Create it before the while(1) and just re-use it?

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution but my requirement is: each thread is gonna work for 15 microseconds then it should go to block state. The next thread should awaken after 1 microsecond. Thus making 1 microsecond of delay between each execution of threads. If I'll set the interval to 1 microsecond, it'll work only once and continuing ticking after every 1 micro sec. Which is not what I want.

Comment: Ohwait - you'e continually creating threads as well.  Why do you need more than one thread?  I'm confused here.

Comment: 1. The program goes to defunct state and I think you need to add pthread_join. 2. By reviewing the stack trace generated by running your program, it looks like all threads go to wait pthread_cond_wait at somepoint.

Comment: I am just adding output as an answer just for discussion. Don't vote on that.

Comment: I think you can use a separate thread(e.g. timer thread) to wakeup other threads after specific interval.

Comment: @MartinJames I want 10 or more # of threads to perform a task one after another (it helps me to have lower virtual runtime of each thread in comparison to those processes which will use the CPU core in 1 microseconds of idle time between thread's execution ).

Answer (score 2):

POSIX says:

> It is not safe to use the pthread_cond_signal() function in a signal handler that is invoked asynchronously.

Most likely you end up corrupting the state of `pthread_cond_wait`/`pthread_cond_signal` and anything can happen.

Don't mix threads and signal handlers, it leads only to madness. There are very few things you're allowed to do inside a signal handler, even fewer that are thread related, it's very hard to ensure that the right thread ends up handling the right signal, etc.

If you're doing threads anyway implement a timer in one thread that calculates how much time it needs to sleep to deliver the next event (don't just hardcode it to your timer period since that will make your timer drift), sleep that much and call `pthread_cond_signal`.

Also, it's bad form to have naked `pthread_cond_signal` calls and most often a bug. You might get unlucky and call it just before the other thread does the `pthread_cond_wait` and your signal will get lost. The normal thing to do is to set a variable (protected by a mutex, that's why `pthread_cond_signal` wants a mutex) and then signal that the variable is set.

If you think this is too much work, condition variables are probably not the right mechanism in this case and you should use semaphores instead. Incidentally `sem_post` is legal to call from a signal handler according to POSIX, but I still think it's a bad idea to mix threads with signals.

Comment: Thankyou for such a thorough response. It looks promising. I'll implement sem_post also and come back to this answer. I also want to see others views.